# Loop over dataframe and update dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

Hi I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'Name':['A','B','C','A'],
               'ID':['a1','b1','c1','a1'],
              'Age':[15,16,32,18]})
```

My desired output is a dictionary:

```
dic={'Name':['A','B','C'],
'ID':['a1','b1','c1'],
'Age':[18,16,32],
'Count':[2,1,1]}
```

Basically it loops over the df['Name'] and Count occurrence as well as update attributes. For example, 'A' occurs twice, so its Count is 2 and the latest Age is 18, the original 15 is updated.

What I have tried is to do a simple count but I don't know how to add attributes and update them:

```
dic={}

for i in list(df['Security Name']):
  if i not in dic['Name']:
      dic[i]=1
   else:
      dic[i]+=1
```

Comment: I'm confused on your desired output. Is your "Count" variable supposed to represent the frequency of the alphabetically sorted parameters in your "Name" column? In addition, is your "Age" column only supposed to contain the highest age value for a given "Name" value?

Comment: Count is to simply count the frequency. The Age is the most recent one not necessarily the highest age value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`groupby_agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html) with a custom dictionary of aggregate functions:

```
# By default keep the last values of the group
funcs = {k: (k, 'last') for k in df.columns}

# Update with custom operations
funcs.update({'Count': ('Name', 'size')})

# Apply the aggregation
out = df.groupby('Name').agg(**funcs).to_dict('list')
print(out)

# Output
{'Name': ['A', 'B', 'C'],
 'ID': ['a1', 'b1', 'c1'],
 'Age': [18, 16, 32],
 'Count': [2, 1, 1]}
```

Comment: Hi Corralien, I revised the question, could you please take a look at the new one? I'd like to create a dynamic dictionary after each dataset feed

Comment: Don't do that, it's a very bad practice. Create a new question with your new problem. It's not fair for @Ynjxsjmh. Me and he gave a good answer to your original problem. Please rollback your edit. Thanks.

Comment: My apology. New to the stack overflow. I will create a new one. Could you please look into it later? Many thanks

Comment: Yes with pleasure. I would as many other users like @mozway.

Comment: I have posted the new one. Please take a look when you have time thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can do `groupby` with named aggregation then convert the result to dictionary

```py
out = (df.groupby('Name', as_index=False)
       .agg(**{'Count': ('Name', 'size'),
               'ID': ('ID', 'first'),
               'Age': ('Age', 'last')})
       .to_dict('list'))
```

```
print(out)

{'Name': ['A', 'B', 'C'], 'Count': [2, 1, 1], 'ID': ['a1', 'b1', 'c1'], 'Age': [18, 16, 32]}
```

Comment: Thank you! This is an elegant solution compared with dictionary update. Could you elaborate the kwargs under the context a bit?

Comment: @Derek Take `'Count': ('Name', 'size')` as an example, it means create `Count` column based on the the `size` of `Name` column.

Comment: Thanks for replying! I understand the function part, what I am a bit unfamiliar with is the **kwargs syntax. I tried to get rid of it and it throws me an error.  This chuck of code is reusable for me so try to understand this syntax

Comment: @Derek. I used dictionary update because if you have N columns in your real case, I think you don't want to type `{'col1': 'last', 'col2': 'last', 'col3': 'last', ... 'colN': 'last', 'special_col': 'size'}`. If you use a newer version of Python (but I don't know), you can use `{k: (k, 'last') for k in df.columns} | {'Count': ('Name', 'size')}` which is probably more elegant....

Answer (score 0):

You can use the pandas function call on the Dataframe object called pd.DataFrame.to_dict(). This will convert your dataframe object to a dictonary object. You can then use the collections.Counter object on dic['ID'] to create a counter map of your ID's.

Example:

```
import collections.Counter

df=pd.DataFrame({'Name':['A','B','C','A'],
               'ID':['a1','b1','c1','a1'],
              'Age':[15,16,32,18]})
dict = df.to_dict()
dict['Count'] = collections.Counter(dict['ID'])
```